# Object of a class does not name a type

Tags: c++, object, types, compilation, header

I know this question has been asked many times, but none of the other threads were entirely applicable and I genuinely can't find my error. So I have 2 header files,depositor.h and name.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "name.h"
using namespace std;
class name;
class depositor
{
private:
    string ssnum;
    string fname;
    string lname;
    name info;
public:
    depositor(string f, string l, string s) : info(f, l)
    {
        ssnum = s;
        fname = f;
        lname = l;
    }
    string getssnum();
    info.getfname()
    info.getlname();
    void printffname();
    void printllname();
    void printssnum();
};




#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class name
{
private:
string fname;
string lname;
public:
name(string f, string l)
    {
        fname = f;
        lname = l;
    }
    string getfname();
    string getlname();
    void printfname();
    void printlname();
};
```

Both are in separate files, and I declared an object of class name (info) in depositor, yet when I run the code, Code Blocks tell me "'info' does not name a type." Going through other threads, people have suggested this is a compilation error, and have suggested using a forward declaration; unless I've used it improperly that hasn't helped. For the life of me I can't see what's wrong with the code; I've declared other objects in the exact same way and they work fine, but for some reason this instance isn't legal. Can anyone make a suggestion?

Update: Reading more up on the issue, it seems like it happens often when two classes are in the same file, or there is recursive .h use. I had an issue similar to that earlier, but I fixed it and doesn't seem to be possible in this instance, since name.h doesn't include any of my own headers. I'm still left wondering how there is an issue here, is it possible something is up with code blocks?

Comment: Get rid of the forward declaration of `name`. You don't need it if `name.h` contains the declaration of `class name`, and if it doesn't, the forward declaration isn't sufficient to tell the compiler about its constructor.

Comment: Taking it out doesn't make a difference; I didn't initially have it there and I only included it out of desperation, to be honest. But is there something else wrong with the code that you notice? It looks fine to me, but it's entirely probable that I'm missing something really obvious that someone else will spot.

Comment: Is the second file `name.h`? It's curious you didn't get an error on the declaration of `info`. NB You should initialize all the fields the way you're initializing `info`.

Comment: Name.h is the second file I posted here, but I don't know the order Code Blocks compiles them. There are two other objects I'm using in other header files, and I initialized them in the exact same way I did for info, but it alone doesn't work.

Comment: Bizarre. I would also point out that you don't need `fname` and `lname` in `depositor`. You could try putting the constructor definition into `depositor.cpp`.

Comment: Yea fname and lname are only there so I could get the program working, when I finish it they'll be gone. If I put  the constructor in the .CPP, do I include the info constructor as well? And do I need to denote that in the .h, like I would with a function prototype.

Comment: You could put the `name` constructor into `name.cpp`. Yes you need a prototype.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that when I get home, thanks!